# Getting element id from Kendo UI treeview drag and drop

Tags: kendo-ui

On the drop event you get back an object that allows you to get the source and destination elements, however I can't see anything available in these objects that helps me identify them uniquely against the datasource.

When I originally databound all of these objects I set an id for each item, but that id is not available in the drop event source/destination elements.

The documentation on the Kendo UI site only goes as far as explaining that there is source/destination objects, not how to do anything with them.

I want to get the source and destination ids so that I can go to the database, remove the source and add it to the destination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So by process of some voodoo magic you can get what you need like so:

```
e.sender.dataItem(e.destinationNode)

_childrenOptions: Object
_events: Object
_loaded: false
children: J.extend.init
dirty: false
enabled: true
hasChildren: true
id: 3
index: 2
items: ct.extend.init[0]
parent: function (){return i}
text: "Sales"
uid: "fedfd9ca-83bf-45ba-a14d-4127f8cc1560"
__proto__: n.extend.r
```